# CPU governor going nuts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: power-management, cpu, amd-processor, tlp

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with an AMD CPU and, with or without `tlp`, the governor seems to not really do a good job, as the fan is always active and it always produces a lot of heat. This is very annoying and I believe it also causes the battery to last less.

I'm using the GNOME cpufreq applet and, if I set it to powersave, CPU frequency is locked to 1.30 GHz and it's a bit quieter, but the issue seems to be that it doesn't really understand when to go idle. The same machine on Windows barely does any sound when powered on and not doing anything power-demanding, while on Ubuntu it always looks like it's overheating despite doing nothing.

Any tips?

Comment: What happens with governor "ondemand"? What laptop model, CPU and GPU do you have? What happens if you turn cpufreq-utils off and use tlp only?

Comment: With ondemand the CPU goes up to 3-4 GHz even when I'm doing nothing and the fan goes wild as a consequence. I have an HP G6 laptop with an AMD A12 APU. How do I turn cpufreq-utils off?

Comment: With no load and no `cpufreq-utils` my processor also runs at top speeds but CPU utilization is low so temps don't climb and fan doesn't come on. In fact it only comes on when using Windows. This "bug" appeared for me about 8 months ago or so? Anyway I've never paid it that much attention. As far as how you turn off cpufreq-utils I have no clue because I've never installed it. To stop `tlp` I use `sudo systemctl disable tlp`.